# u-boot instead of barebox in imx6-phyBOARD mira

Tags: arm, u-boot, imx6

I am trying to load u-boot in imx6-phyBOARD mira which is having Barebox as bootloader. I have generated a custom u-boot image referring imx porting guide. Now when I try to run u-boot.imx/u-boot.bin using 'bootm' command then it is getting stuck. 
What could be the probable reason?
Is there any other method rather than 'bootm' to load u-boot from barebox?
Can I get some guidance and tips to make this successful?

Thankyou.

Comment: barebox and u-boot are both boot loaders.  `bootm` is to boot an **application image**.  But u-boot is not an application like *linux*, etc.  You need to tell/configure u-boot that some other boot loader ran first.  I am not sure this use case is supported.  Normally you would **replace** barebox with u-boot by flashing/replacing it.  Of course that might be dangerous as you can brick your device.  The software solution may require a soldering iron :)

Comment: Yes I tried replacing barebox with u-boot. After reset board does not boots with u-boot. Is there any role of magic number or HAB in phytec mira board which does not allow u-boot image to run?

Comment: Uboot can be signed as well.  It is possible you need some code update.  I think imx6 has Dcd as well to configure pins, etc.  The boot device (ddr) on the Mira board needs to be setup.

Comment: I've also worked with the phyboard mira. It doesn't run any security mechanisms like HAB what so ever by default. If the board refuses to boot you most likely flashed the wrong bootloader or chosen a wrong location. For barebox you need to leave the first 2 blocks alone (on the emmc version the command would be: `dd if=barebox of=/dev/mmcblk3 seek=2 skip=2`). You could try to replace `barebox.bin` with your `u-boot` image. Before touching the bootloader make sure you can boot from sd card to be able to recover the system.